# Function to return two values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that returns 2 values start and end where start = end and end = start + 10

How can I achieve that in Python?

Comment: `return value, value + 10`? But *"start = end and end = start + 10"* seem mutually exclusive...

Answer (score 3):

You can do that simply by:

```
def foo(start):
    end = start + 10
    return start, end

a, b = foo(100)
print(a,b)
#Output: 100 110
```

Here `start` is an integer, but if `start` is an array then:

```
def foo(start):
    result = []
    for s in start:
        result.append((s,s+ 10))
    return result

result = foo([1,2,3,4,5])
for a,b in result:
     print(a,b)

#Output: 
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
5 15
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this, but I for got to add, I need 5 rows of this data

So Imagine you have a row of 1 - 5

I want the function to return something like this

(1, 10)
(10, 20)
(20, 30) etc

Comment: By row do you mean array? So `start = [1,2,3,4,5]` like this?

Comment: yes so imagine you have a table with 5 rows 1-5

Comment: I edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: this is what I have done based on your code:

```def foo(start):
    result = []
    for _ in range(10):
      end = start +92.3
      start = end
      result.append((start, end))
    return result```

foo(13)

I want it to be like so:
[(13, 105.3),
 (105.3, 197.6),
 (197.6, 289.9),
 (289.9, 382.2),
 (382.2, 474.5),
 (474.5, 566.8),
 (568.8, 659.0999999999999),
 (659.0999999999999, 751.3999999999999),
 (751.3999999999999, 843.6999999999998),
 (843.6999999999998, 935.9999999999998)]

Answer (score 0):

Python function can return many values in one call like:

```
def test_return(input1, input2, input3):

    return input1*2, input2+2, input3-1

a, b, c = test_return(2,4,6)
print(a,b,c)
```

### Output 4 6 5